# Webform response: "Illegal information. Data not submitted."

Tags: webforms

I have a very simple webform (ie. name, email, comments) that has begun giving this response to any submissions, no matter what they are:

[image: Illegal information. Data not submitted.]

Has anyone seen that before? The results are still saved in the webform but it causes confusion and people also enter their comments multiple times as a result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that message is triggered by the [_webform_submission_spam_check](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!includes!webform.submissions.inc/function/_webform_submission_spam_check/7) function. Looking at the code, it seems to check the following regular expression:

```
'/(b?cc\s?:)|(content\-type:)/i', $to . "\n" . $subject . "\n" . $from . "\n" . $headers
```

Maybe some of the submissions contain "cc" or "bcc" or "content-type"?

Comment: Wow, brilliant. And weird. An email was configured to send from the form with a subject line that began with "CC: " and as soon as I changed that the message went away. Thanks!